# Javascript Function scope / accessibility

Tags: javascript, function

I'm no javascript expert and I'm trying to find out how I can ensure my functions are available for all my pages.

My setup:

index.php > my main page where I load my javascript functions
sl.php > a back end script sending html back

```
$(document).ready(
    function ButtonManager()
        {   
            $( "button" ).click(function() 
                {    
                    $.ajax
                       ({
                           type: 'POST',
                           url: 'php/sl.php',
                           data: 'test=1',
                           cache: false, 
                           async: false,
                           dataType: 'html', 
                           success: function(result) 
                                {   $('#mydiv').html(result);               
                                }
                        }); 
                 }

         });
</pre>
```

In my index.php, I have a button that triggers this function and it works fine. Basically it retrieves some html containing other buttons using the same function as the one described above. The problem is that the function declared in index.php does not seem to be known by the html I get back from sl.php

Is there a way to make my ButtonManager function available for the html code that comes back from the server ? The html I get back from the server is inserted in the page where the function is declared.

**UPDATE 29/07 :** 
Here is an example of the buttons I use
TEST 
I have such a button in index.php and when I click on it, it posts test=1 to sl.php
In return I get some content that I insert into #mydiv. The process works fine except that buttons included in the sl.php output do not react at all when I click on them.

TJ Crowder:
I have tried your solution (the one without the ready tag) but now even the buttons in index.php don't react any more.

Here is a simplified version to clear any interferences with something else.

```
    var MyApp;
    MyApp = MyApp || {};


    (function() {

        MyApp.ButtonManager = ButtonManager;
        function ButtonManager() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                alert ('oo');
            });
        }
    })();
```

In the end, the only thing I would like to do is have one location to manage all buttons with sometimes buttons being used in index.php sometimes elsewhere.

Thanks!
Laurent

Comment: use event delegation. use Jquery .on instead .click.

Comment: @ Tomalak: You *changed* the OP's code, rather than just formatting it.

Comment: @ user: Your code is invalid, it has mismatched `}`. Please paste the code you're actually using.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually [fixed his code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25009824/2). Ah well.

Comment: @Tomalak: Fixing code in questions is a bad idea. You don't know that it isn't broken in the OP's real code. You may fix it in a way that's different from their code. For instance, maybe his code actually looks like this: http://pastie.org/9428827 We don't know. Editing the question with assumptions is not useful. (I appreciate the code edit in my answer, though, even though I didn't notice it at the time and ended up ovewriting it with something similar -- answers are fundamentally different from questions. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My assumption went like this: The OP copied his `ButtonManager` function out of a larger context and slapped on `$(document).ready()` manually, making a minor mistake in the process. I assumed the question would not be about a high level concept like scope if the code itself would not even compile. But you are right, fixing it still wasn't a good idea.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, reasonable assumption. The weird thing is there's more going on than just a missing `function() {` on the `ready` line, there's also an extra `}` closing the click handler. We'll just have to wait for the OP to resurface... :-)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your answers. I'm sorry about the copy/paste mistake I made. I was writing the post while travelling in a shaky train and using my touchpad to clear the non relevant code. I'll post some feedback right after the TJ Crowder's answer here below.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question has syntax errors. I'm going to guess your code actually looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ButtonManager() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/sl.php',
                data: 'test=1',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

If so, your `ButtonManager` function is only accessible *within* the anonymous function you've passed to `ready`; it's not accessible outside it.

You can make it a global, but the global namespace is already **really** crowded, so I'd only create one more global, `MyApp` or something, and make your functions properties on that object:

```
// Declare it -- this is a no-op if it's already been declared by another script
var MyApp;

// Use it if it's already initialized by another script, or initialize it if not
MyApp = MyApp || {};

// Your original code
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Make ButtonManager a property of MyApp
    MyApp.ButtonManager = ButtonManager;
    function ButtonManager() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/sl.php',
                data: 'test=1',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Using it:

```
var mgr = MyApp.ButtonManager();
```

There, I've left your `ButtonManager` inside the `ready` callback on the theory that you have other code in that callback that needs to wait for `ready`, but just creating the `ButtonManager` function doesn't need to wait for `ready`. If you don't have code that needs to wait for ready, you can do this:

```
// Declare it -- this is a no-op if it's already been declared by another script
var MyApp;

// Use it if it's already initialized by another script, or initialize it if not
MyApp = MyApp || {};

// Use a scoping function to avoid creating more globals
(function() {
    // Make ButtonManager a property of MyApp
    MyApp.ButtonManager = ButtonManager;
    function ButtonManager() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/sl.php',
                data: 'test=1',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

---

Side note: The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that function names start with a lowercase letter unless the function is meant to be called via the `new` operator. So in this case, `buttonManager` rather than `ButtonManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, TJ Crowder put me on the right track.

In my main page, I have isolated my function to make it global:

```
<pre>
function ButtonManager()
{ same ajax call }

in my server side output I have added:
<script>
var mgr = ButtonManager();
</script>
</pre>
```

When I now click on one of the button coming from the server, the function is correctly executed!

Thanks!